# Let $(X,\tau)$ be topological. prove that $\tau$ is the discrete on X if and only if $x\in X,\{x\}\in \tau$

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\tau)$ be topological. prove that $\tau$ is the discrete on X if and only if $x\in X,\{x\}\in \tau$

My attempt:

suppose $\tau$ is discrete topology then for $x\in X $ then $\{x\}\in \tau$
but what about other side can any help please

Comment: What's the definition of discrete space?

Comment: @KennyLau...Let d be the metric on a nonempty set X. Prove that the topology on  X generated by d is the discrete topology.

Comment: So what's the definition of the discrete topology?

Comment: The question as written does not make sense: show that a statement depending on $X$ and $\tau$ is equivalent to a statement depending on $X$, $\tau$, and $x$. Perhaps you meant to write something like: "***for all*** $x\in X,\ \{x\}\in\tau$"?

Comment: For me the *definition* of discrete topology is *"every single point subset is open"*, which is same thing as saying "for every $x\in X, \{x\} \in \tau$". So it will be better to write what definition you are using for "discrete topology".

Comment: How about using the definition that "Discrete topology is the power set of $X$?"

Comment: @Mathmore That might be the definition the OP is using. We have no way of knowing if he won't tell us. We might be able to make a reasonable guess if, in "showing his work", he had shown us how he proved the implication from left to right, instead of just telling us that he's done it.

Comment: @bof Totally agreed! One must read [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) before asking a question on this site. The rules are meant for us only to get better answers. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

What you meant to say is this:

Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space. Then $\tau$ is the discrete topology iff for all $x \in X$, the set $\{x\}$ is open.

To see this use that for any $A \subseteq X$: $A = \cup\{\{x\}: x \in A\}$ and the union axiom for a topology.

Comment: I don't see the use of answering the question when nobody knows what it means. You have neither gotten the OP to reveal what definition of "discrete topology" he is using, nor have you conjecture that definition to be. My guess: $(X,\tau)$ is discrete iff $\overline A=A$ for every set $A\subseteq X.$

Comment: @bof I assume the only "true" definition: $\tau = \mathscr{P}(X)$.